# Fortran90 wrong output

Tags: fortran, fortran90

i'm working on a small program for a course in university and i'm almost finished but somehow it doesn't work as i want it to work.

Now, the output file gravity1.dat should give me values unequal to 0. But it doesnt... Somewhere in the last formula where i calculate g(surf), one of the variables is 0. If tried almost everything in my power to correct it but i can't seem to fix it.

```
program gravity

implicit none
real(8) Lx,Ly,sx,sy,xsphere,ysphere,r,A,rho1,rho2,dx,G
integer np,nel,nelx,nely,i,nnx,nny,j,counter,nsurf
real(8),dimension(:),allocatable :: xcgrid
real(8),dimension(:),allocatable :: ycgrid
real(8),dimension(:),allocatable :: xgrid
real(8),dimension(:),allocatable :: ygrid
real(8),dimension(:),allocatable :: rho
real(8),dimension(:),allocatable :: xsurf, gsurf
real(8),dimension(:),allocatable :: ysurf

nnx=11.
nny=11.
Lx=10.
Ly=10.
nelx=nnx-1.
nely=nny-1.
nel=nelx*nely
np=nnx*nny
sx=Lx/nelx
sy=Ly/nely
xsphere=5.
ysphere=5.
r=3.
nsurf=7  !number of gravimeters

dx=Lx/(nsurf-1.)

!==========================================================

allocate(xgrid(np))
allocate(ygrid(np))

counter=0
do i=1,nnx
    do j=1,nny
    counter=counter+1   
    xgrid(counter)=dble(i-1)*sx
    ygrid(counter)=dble(j-1)*sy
    end do
end do

call write_two_columns(np,xgrid,ygrid,'grid_init1.dat')
!==========================================================

allocate(xcgrid(np))
allocate(ycgrid(np))


counter=0
do i=1,nnx-1
    do j=1,nny-1
    counter=counter+1   
    xcgrid(counter)=dble(i-1)*sx+0.5*sx
    ycgrid(counter)=dble(j-1)*sy+0.5*sy
    end do
end do

call write_two_columns(np,xcgrid,ycgrid,'gridc_init1.dat')
!==========================================================

allocate(rho(nel))

rho1=3000. !kg/m^3
rho2=3200. !kg/m^3

do i=1,nel  
    if (sqrt((xsphere-xcgrid(i))**2)+((ysphere-ycgrid(i))**2)<r) then
    rho(i)=3200.
    else 
    rho(i)=3000.
    end if
end do

call write_three_columns(nel,xcgrid,ycgrid,rho,'inclusion1.dat')
!==========================================================

allocate(xsurf(nsurf))
allocate(ysurf(nsurf))

do i=1,nsurf
xsurf(i)=(i-1)*dx
ysurf(i)=ly
end do

call write_two_columns(nsurf,xsurf,ysurf,'surf_init1.dat')
!==========================================================

allocate(gsurf(nsurf))

G=0.000000000066738480 !m^3 kg^-1 s^-2

do i=1,nsurf
    do j=1,nel
    gsurf(i)=gsurf(i)+(-2.*G*(((rho(i)-rho1)*(ycgrid(counter)-ysurf(i)))/((xcgrid(counter)-xsurf(i))**2.+(ycgrid(counter)-ysurf(i))**2.))*sx*sy)

    end do
end do

call write_two_columns(nsurf,xsurf,gsurf,'gravity1.dat')

deallocate(xgrid)
deallocate(ygrid)
deallocate(xcgrid)
deallocate(ycgrid)
deallocate(xsurf)
deallocate(ysurf)
deallocate(gsurf)
end program
```

The subroutines used:

```
!===========================================

subroutine write_two_columns (nnn,xxx,yyy,filename)
implicit none
integer i,nnn
real(8) xxx(nnn),yyy(nnn)
character(LEN=*) filename

open(unit=123,file=filename,action='write')
do i=1,nnn
write(123,*) xxx(i),yyy(i)
end do
close(123)
end subroutine
```

and the other subroutine:

```
!===========================================

subroutine write_three_columns (nnn,xxx,yyy,zzz,filename)
implicit none
integer i,nnn
real(8) xxx(nnn),yyy(nnn),zzz(nnn)
character(LEN=*) filename
open(unit=123,file=filename,action='write')
do i=1,nnn
write(123,*) xxx(i),yyy(i),zzz(i)
end do
close(123)
end subroutine

!===========================================
```

Comment: I do not have time to debug your program. But if you are just learning try to learn some basic Fortran habits. Use indentation. You use it in some places, but not enough. It greatly improves readability. Place your subroutines in a module. It will enable some error checks. Then you can also use assumed shape arrays `(:,:)` and you will not need to pass the size of the arrays. Do not use real(8), it is not portable and it is a "magic number". Use `kind(1.d0)`, `selected_real_kind` or `rea64`. Learn error checking options of your compiler. You do not have to deallocate allocatables in Fortran95.

Comment: Note that your gsurf calculation does not use j but counter. This will certainly lead to unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be `(rho(j)-rho1)`? You fill `rho(1:nel)`, but only use `rho(1:7)`!

By the way, be careful with your variable initialization... You assign `real`s to `integer`s, and do mixed type arithmetics. Be careful with this as it might lead to unexpected results. Use your compiler to detect those issues.